# Access property inside Ember component

Tags: ember.js

Need your help folks. How can I access property inside the component. Something like this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  cMsg: Ember.computed('msg', function() {
            return `${this.get('msg')} , ${this.get('msg')}`;
        }),

  selectedDomain: { msgPrefix: 'cMsg???' },  
});
```

Here is the twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/9acda203a89dbd3892059170ab665d08?openFiles=components.hello-there.js%2C

Comment: `selectedDomain:Ember.computed('cMsg',function(){ return { msgPrefix: this.get('cMsg')} })`  Not sure about exact problem you are facing

Comment: I have not tried that. Let me try to run it.

Comment: Thanks so much @kumkanillam! Dunno why I did not try that.  It seems it is working they way I want.  https://ember-twiddle.com/9acda203a89dbd3892059170ab665d08?openFiles=templates.components.hello-there.hbs%2C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time we miss the usage of custom helper and computed property. In this case you can write computed property,

```
selectedDomain: Ember.computed('cMsg', function() { 
    return { msgPrefix: this.get('cMsg') } 
})
```